# SVN Edge not authenticating correctly with domain controller

Tags: active-directory, ssl, svn, starttls

SVN Edge (version 4.0.10-3880.131) not authenticating correctly with domain controller.

I have SVN Edge setup and working perfectly when I use LDAP Security Level of NONE..

However when set to SSL, TLS, or STARTTLS. I get a wrong username/password error when logging in with a active directory account. See configuration below:

[image: SVN Authentication image]

Log files show:

```
2015-11-10 10:17:07,113 [qtp1791392392-61] WARN  security.CsvnAuthenticationProvider  - Authentication against Apache failed
```

Jetty log:

```
   127.0.0.1 -  -  [10/Nov/2015:10:16:58 -0700] "GET /csvn/login/auth HTTP/1.1" 200 6616 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [10/Nov/2015:10:17:07 -0700] "POST /csvn/j_spring_security_check HTTP/1.1" 302 0 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [10/Nov/2015:10:17:07 -0700] "GET /csvn/login/authfail?login_error=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 0 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [10/Nov/2015:10:17:07 -0700] "GET /csvn/login/auth?login_error=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 6751 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [10/Nov/2015:10:17:15 -0700] "POST /csvn/j_spring_security_check HTTP/1.1" 302 0 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [10/Nov/2015:10:17:15 -0700] "GET /csvn/login/authfail?login_error=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 0 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [10/Nov/2015:10:17:15 -0700] "GET /csvn/login/auth?login_error=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 6754 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [10/Nov/2015:10:18:03 -0700] "POST /csvn/j_spring_security_check HTTP/1.1" 302 0 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [10/Nov/2015:10:18:03 -0700] "GET /csvn/login/authfail?login_error=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 0 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [10/Nov/2015:10:18:03 -0700] "GET /csvn/login/auth?login_error=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 6749 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [10/Nov/2015:10:20:39 -0700] "GET /csvn/log/list?sort=date&order=desc HTTP/1.1" 200 16811 
127.0.0.1 -  -  [10/Nov/2015:10:21:02 -0700] "GET /csvn/images/sort_desc.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1127
```

Again without LDAP Security turned on, all AD accounts are able to login successfully. I'm assuming I am setting up SVN Edge incorrectly, any ideas on what I should change?

Bump

Answer (score 1):

Kind of late to this.  I think you might need to check that the AD server support SSL and TLS, or STARTTLS port by talking to LDAP administrators.  You can use the [lpd tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc771022(v=ws.11)) or [ADexplorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/adexplorer) to make sure the required ports are open and able to connect to the LDAP server.  Then you can use a command line openssl and try the command

```
openssl s_client -connect yourADserver:yourADSErversecure port -tls1_2
```

to check whether you can connect it with the specific TLS protocol. My sample use TLS 1.2 protocol.  I am able to get mine working using the setting STARTTLS selection.

One more thing, check the file svn_viewvc_http.conf under the conf directory in Subversion Edge installation directory which contains the LDAP settings generated by the system. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I found that once I changed to SSL or TLS, I had to change the LDAP Server port from the default 3268 (389 in my case). I also needed the LDAP Bind DN and password, but that may have been true with the NONE security level setting as well. [Subversion Edge Version 5.1.4, by the way, in case that makes a difference]